# Mail delivery failed from SO contact us part

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

Today I asked Contact Us part for merging my two accounts and after request it said you will receive an email shortly but an email sended to my email box like that :

[image]

Did I do something wrong ?

Comment: You filled in the form and got this? That would indeed be very strange!

Comment: @Pekka웃 , yeah it seems no problem with filled form and it mentioned I will receive and email shortly but I got this !

Comment: Seems strange that their policy would pick that up, given that it looks like a Yahoo! email address (at least on the surface and after a few minutes of Googling).

Comment: If you received this in response to filling out the form (and *not* sending an E-Mail to Stack Overflow directly) it's a bug on their end.

Comment: We were trying out a different ticket-handling system over the last few weeks, and switched the form to use the submitter's email as the "from" address because that helped work around a couple quirks of that system. We have now switched back to our normal system, so I'll switch this back later today as well. Sorry about the inconvenience.